# django simple history plugin: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'

Tags: django, django-simple-history

I'm trying using django-simple-history plugin with django version 1.10

According to documentation:

1. Installed plugin using the following command:

   ```
   pip install django-simple-history
   ```
2. Added simple_history to INSTALLED_APPS

   ```
   INSTALLED_APPS = [  
       ...  
       'simple_history',  
   ]
   ```
3. To track history for a model, created an instance of simple_history.models.HistoricalRecords on the model:

   ```
   class ModelClass(models.Model):  
       name1 = models.CharField(max_length=300)  
       name2 = models.CharField(max_length=300)  
       name3 = models.CharField(max_length=300)  
       history = HistoricalRecords(table_name='sampls_modelclass_history')  
       class Meta:  
           db_table = "sample_modelclass"
   ```
4. To allow viewing previous model versions on the Django admin site, inherited from the simple_history.admin.SimpleHistoryAdmin class when registering model with the admin site:

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin  
   from simple_history.admin import SimpleHistoryAdmin  
   from .models import ModelClass  
   admin.site.register(ModelClass, SimpleHistoryAdmin)
   ```
5. When I try to enter 'History' on particular instance of ModelClass in admin I'm getting the following exception:

   ```
   TypeError: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'
   ```

**Traceback:**

```
Environment:  
Request Method: GET  
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/org/modelclass/1/history/  
Django Version: 1.10  
Python Version: 2.7.11  
Installed Applications:  
['etc',  
 'org',  
 'django.contrib.admin',  
 'django.contrib.auth',  
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',  
 'django.contrib.sessions',  
 'django.contrib.messages',  
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',  
 'simple_history']  
Installed Middleware:  
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',  
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',  
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',  
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',  
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',  
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']  
**Traceback:**  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner  
  39.             response = get_response(request)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response  
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response  
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper  
  544.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)  
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view  
  149.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func  
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner  
  211.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\simple_history\admin.py" in history_view  
  79.                       dictionary=context, current_app=request.current_app)  
Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/org/modelclass/1/history/  
Exception Value: render() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dictionary'
```

Please advise resolution!

Answer (score 0):

That argument was removed in Django 1.10. The package you are using seems not to be compatible with that version.

Comment: Thank you lot! I've found the following in django docs: Changed in Django 1.8:
The context argument used to be called dictionary. That name is deprecated in Django 1.8 and will be removed in Django 1.10.
I've raised related issue in django-simple-history issue list.